# HttpPlatformHandler error with Django app hosted in IIS

Tags: django, iis, waitress, httpplatformhandler

I have a Django site I'm developing, which uses Waitress as the WSGI server.  When I run the `server.py` file from the command line, everything works as expected.

As a next step toward rolling it out, I'm trying to "wire in" the application to the Windows IIS web server.  After a lot of searching around I found [this article](https://adrianjnkns.medium.com/django-on-iis-b33574dbd510) which is fairly recent and provides a comprehensive set of steps to get it working with `HttpPlatformHandler` (which I take to be the preferred option, as Microsoft reports [they are no longer maintaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022) `WFastCGI`).  I also took into account the author's caveat regarding lack of expertise, which is why I'm using `Waitress` rather than the Django development server as he did.

The issue I'm having is that with IIS configured to host the Django app, the browser connection never goes through.  While the browser makes its connection attempt, the Windows event log on my server shows a recurring error every minute or so:

[image]

Note, each time the error is triggered, the process number and port number are both different; the Error Code of -2147023436 however is always the same.

Additionally, each time the error occurs a new log file is generated in my Django project folder, but the file is completely empty.

[image]

**I did the usual google searches for the HttpPlatformHandler error code and event ID but didn't find anything helpful (to me).  I'd appreciate any kind of pointer to where the problem might be.**

Further info about the environment I'm using:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard
- IIS Version 10
- HttpPlatformHandler 1.2
- Python 3.10.11
- Django 4.2.7
- Waitress 2.1.2

`server.py` file:

```
from waitress import serve
from django_project.wsgi import application

if __name__=='__main__':
    serve(application, port='8090')
```

`web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
            <add name="hphForCSCR" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="D:\mystuff\django-projects\code\cscr\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" arguments="D:\mystuff\django-projects\code\cscr\server.py" startupTimeLimit="60" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="D:\mystuff\django-projects\code\cscr\server.log" processesPerApplication="1">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="8090" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\mystuff\django-projects\code\cscr" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="django_project.settings" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Site settings in IIS (note, the listen port is 8080 intentionally -- I already realized that putting it on 8090 caused a conflict with waitress):

[image]

Handler mapping:

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few common issues to run Python web apps on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: I checked the link you provided and found that Configure httpPlatform was not mentioned in your post, so please check whether you Configure httpPlatform?

Comment: @samwu -- see the web.config content and the screen shot under "Handler mapping."  Yes, I did install HttpPlatformHandler and it was configured as the handler to use in the IIS site (cscr_ws).

Comment: You can also use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: The request never makes it through to begin with, so the app does not have any logging to provide information.

Comment: What I mean is to use this [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view the detailed request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I went through the instructions in the link you provided, augmenting them with this related article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7   But after installing the tracing feature in IIS and configuring the tracing for my cscr_ws site, it does not generate any log files at all.  Whatever condition it is that triggers the HttpPlatformHandler error in the Windows log, it's apparently too "early" in the connection process for IIS to provide any useful information on its handling of the browser request.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks but I've already decided that I'm abandoning IIS as the hosting platform.  There are many alternatives such as Apache (which I've already set up for testing and it's already provided a working solution with less effort and fewer dependencies).  And if that doesn't work out, there are other OSs.

Comment: For future readers, 1) don't use Python virtual environment (it leaves files all over the places so impossible to get file permissions right) 2) Delete everything from wfastcgi tutorials as you won't need them. You can see this post still kept quite a few in `web.config`. 3) Start from the simple test case in my initial comment, and that can help you rule out issues within your own code. 4) Keep a tool like Process Monitor at hand so that you can find out access denied issues with it.

Comment: @samwu Some tips for you. 1) FRT doesn't work well for such file permission issues. 2) It's actually easy to reproduce the issue, if you do create a simple test app based on the Django documentation. But surely it requires some basic Python experience.